Why does a sphere has negative principal curvatures when normal vector is taken to be outward?
I checked several questions that was posted before me. A question from 2015 actually tried to ask the same question as me, but it seems that their question was misunderstood (based on the only answer that was given) due to the fact that they did not provided the direction of their normal vector.
I know that $K>0$ (positive curvature) for a sphere. But when normal vector n is taken to be outward, its principal curvatures become $k_1=k_2=\frac{-1}{R}\rightarrow K=\frac{1}{R^2}$. My intuition tells me that they should be positive as the surface is clearly convex. So what is going on here? I noticed the issue while studying in a cylinder and then proceeded to check for sphere to be sure. In a cylinder, one of the principal curvatures is zero while the other one gives $\frac{-1}{R}$ which is clearly the carbon copy of my question with sphere.
On the other hand, a convex surface is bulged toward n which causes the curvature to be (seemingly) following a path away from n... but this interpretation makes no sense. If I clear this confusion for sphere, then it would clear it for me regarding every possible shape. So, please help me out. Is my definition of n being outward is correct? Or should I take it inward instead?
Edit: I thank @TedShifrin 's comment for its explanation. I was working on a cylinder (and then sphere) when I first noticed the - and the only explanation I could come up was "it is negative because curvature seems to follow a path away from outward n". But since I did not believed in my own explanation, I went out my way to post a question here. I did used this explanation while taking my own notes since they were the only explanation I could come up with. But Ted's comment shows that my explanation was actually true. I guess the actual lesson here is to trust myself a bit more (while being cautious of course).

It is clear from the definition of the $k_i$ that reversing the direction of the normal vector changes the sign of the $k_i$.  This obviously does not affect the sign of $K=k_1 k_2$, so we don't care so much about the sign of the principal curvatures.  Also it does not affect the definition of a minimal surface in $\mathbb R^3$.

@MikhailKatz thanks for your comment. While I do see your point, I thought that for a direction that our eyes perceives as convex, the related principal component should be positive when n is taken outward. And this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature#Classification_of_points_on_a_surface from wikipedia just added to my confusion resulting in this post.

Your question is really about curves, not about surfaces.  Consider the case of an oriented circle in the plane, and try to understand how the (signed) curvature of the circle is computed.

Principal curvatures are normal curvatures; the sign depends on which of the two unit vectors you take as the surface normal. If the curve is bending toward the surface normal, you get a positive normal curvature; if it is bending away, you get a negative normal curvature. If you take the normal to the sphere pointing out, then any curve on the sphere bends away from that normal and has negative normal curvature. You should look at some standard differential geometry texts (for example, mine, linked for free in my profile).

@TedShifrin thank you. So my commentary on the very last paragraph isn't actually non-sensical (I cut that sentence in my post to say "makes no sense") as I thought. Thanks for clearing that up. I guess I should just trust in myself a bit more.
In particular, I actually used this interpretation while taking my own notes after I post this question as it was my only interpretation. But I never thought it to be actually true back then. So again, thank you : )

@MikhailKatz I thank you too.

@TedShifrin Also, I will take a look at the texts you mentioned : )

Perhaps someone could convert these comments into an answer.

There are two natural but conflicting criteria for choosing which normal to use. With a closed surface, we use the outward normal to define the orientation on the surface. It therefore is natural to use it for the Gauss map. This, however, leads to the second fundamental form of the sphere to be negative definite. On the other hand, if the surface is a graph, we use the upward normal to define orientation. It is also natural to define the second fundamental form to have the same signature as the Hessian of the function. For a sphere this is the same as using the inward normal as the Gauss map.
